# Create RDD using key and value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a list that contains tuples of String

```
list = [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("B", "D")]
```

and I have a hashmap that contains

```
hash_map = ("A"-> List("B"), "B" -> List("C", "D"))
```

I want to loop over the `list` and create an RDD in the following way,

```
RDD = [("A", "C"), ("A", "D")]
```

I tried doing this,

```
val result = list.map(d => (d._1, hash_map.get(d._2).map(v => v)))
```

However, it returns

```
OUTPUT:
("A", List("C", "D"))
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this has to do with RDD but this gets you the result you want.

```
val list = List(("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("B", "D"))

val hashMap = Map("A"-> List("B"), "B" -> List("C", "D"))

val r = list.flatMap { case (a, b) =>
  hashMap.getOrElse(b, Nil).map((a, _))
}

println(r)
```